# How does the nonlinear function of KeeLoq work?

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation

I want to know how the nonlinear function of KeeLoq works.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeeLoq) at Wikipedia it says that:

> The NLFSR feedback function is 0x3A5C742E

I understand that `F(a,b,c,d,e) = 3A5C742E`.

Now, he did not say anything about encoding of `a, b, c, d, e`. I consider them as in ASCII. But each letter will have 8-bit. So total would be 40. Could someone explains to me how to compute this function or what is the encoding scheme of `a, b, c, d, e` in order to apply Karnaugh map?

Comment: The $a,\ldots,e$ are bits, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to compute $F(0,0,0,1,0)$, then note that $00010_2 = 2_{10}$ so the result is bit $2$ (counted from $0$ from right to left) of `0x3A5C742E`, or in C terms just `(3A5C742E >> 2) & 1 = 1` This is the standard convention when encoding such Boolean functions.

As another example `F(1,1,1,1,1) = (0x3A5C742E >> 31) & 1 = 0` as $11111_2 = 31_{10}$ etc.

Comment: It extracts the bits from a constant?

Comment: @Melab the constant is just the 32 values for the 32 different inputs. It’s a compact table.

Comment: Elaborate, please.

Comment: @Melab Read the answer, it explains.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you Henno, It is clear now. another example also F(1,0,0,0,0)=0.